# Retrieve data from specific node in Firebase database using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[firebase snippit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBqZQ.png)

Hello all.  I am creating a web app that pulls from a firebase realtime database I have created.  Using javascript I would like to pull the data from a specific node (i.e. "8").

I will then use the keys and values from the node in the web app.

What js/firebase code do I need to pull data from any specific node?

Below is the code we have tried.  Long term goal is to pull data from a random node, but right now I just to find out how to pull from a specific node.  Since the nodes are always going to be a number from 0-49, I don't need to use "length of array" functions when randomizing.  I will use "Math.floor(Math.random() * 49" to give me a random number which I can pass into the index value for the node when I figure out how to access one specifically.

```
ref = firebase.database().ref('articles/');

function setupObservers() {
  ref.on('value',function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val())
    let articleArray = []
    for(key in snapshot.val()) {
      let articleKeys = snapshot.val()[key]
      articleArray.push(articleKeys)
    }
    randomArticle(articleArray)

  })
}


function randomArticle(articleArray) {
  let random = articleArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * articleArray.length)]
  console.log(random)
}

setupObservers()
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: it's a very long JSON file.

Comment: Another advantage of posting it as text is that you can edit it down to the minimum that is needed for what you're asking about. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To read the value from a specific child node of which you know the key, you simply do:

```
ref = firebase.database().ref('articles');
ref.child("8").on('value',function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val())
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  That pretty much did what I wanted.  I appreciate the fast reply!

Comment: Hi, what does the child("8") actually do in this case?